# Can't get last modified date from Uri

Tags: android, uri, android-contentresolver, android-fileprovider

I have some files saved in the private app-specific folder of the app.

If I get a file uri through the FileProvider

```
val fileUri = getUriForFile(this, "$packageName.fileprovider", file)
```

and query the content resolver to get the file metadata

```
contentResolver.query(fileUri, null, null, null, null)
```

and check all the columnNames inside the cursor I'm getting, I can see that there are only two columns, which are `_display_name` and `_size`

What if I wanted to obtain the date of creation/last modification of the file from the uri? Is
there something I could do?

(I know I could get it from the File object, but I'd need it from the uri, the real code is more complex than this example.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What if I wanted to obtain the date of creation/last modification of the file from the uri? Is there something I could do?

That depends a bit on your overall setup.

There's no way to get that information for an arbitrary `Uri`. There's no requirement for, say, Google Drive to provide that information, which is why it's not part of the `OpenableColumns` protocol that you're using (or anything else). So, if the reason you're pushing away from using the `File` is because you have a mixed bag of `Uri` values from various sources, then you're probably in trouble.

If, OTOH, you know that your `Uri` values are *always from your `FileProvider`*, you can reverse-engineer the filesystem path from the `Uri` value, use that to construct a `File`, and get the info that way (or, at least, whatever Android makes available via those `File` methods). Or, if you can live with the creation/modification time information only being available for a subset of your `Uri` list, use the aforementioned hack for your own `FileProvider` `Uri` values and live without the data for `Uri` values that you get from elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you.
Aside from the original app that is saving the files, I would also need the same info inside a different app, where I'm receiving and using the shared Uris of these files.

I imagine I can construct the File objects only while inside the original app, that's why I was interested in finding a way to get info directly from the Uri, so that it would work in both apps.

Maybe I should obtain such info in the original app, and share it along the Uris in a different extra parameter of the intent?

Comment: @LukeB.: "I imagine I can construct the File objects only while inside the original app" -- correct. Depending on where the files are located, another app will not have filesystem access to them to get the information. Plus, having App B try decoding `Uri` values of App A to reverse-engineer the filesystem path is just ugly. "Maybe I should obtain such info in the original app, and share it along the Uris in a different extra parameter of the intent?" -- I guess so. Or, perhaps this should be just one app, rather than two.

Answer (score 1):

So I also wanted to have the same. I use an Intent to let the user pick an image. When a user selects an image from Camera I can get the last modified via:

```kotlin
fun ContentResolver.lastModified(uri: Uri): Instant? {
  val query = query(uri, null, null, null, null)

  query?.use { cursor ->
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      val columnNames = listOf(
        "last_modified", // When selecting an image from the Camera via the Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT action.
        "datetaken", // When sharing an Image from Google Photos into the app.
      )

      val instant = columnNames.firstNotNullOfOrNull {
        val index = cursor.getColumnIndex(it)
        if (!cursor.isNull(index)) {
          Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(cursor.getLong(index))
        } else {
          null
        }
      }

      if (instant == null) {
        val string = cursor.columnNames.map { columnName ->
          columnName to cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName).takeIf { it >= 0 }?.let(cursor::getString)
        }
        Timber.tag("Uri").i(UnsupportedOperationException("Can't get last modified from $string"))
      }

      return instant
    }
  }

  return null
}
```

Note: This might not work for every app, however it's a good first start. Also, when it does not work, it will log an exception via Timber and if you have that wired up to a logging file or Crashlytics, you can progressively add more supported column names.